# Adding ActionListener to JButtons

Tags: java, actionlistener

When attempting to implement ActionListener I receive the following error

> ```
> EmployeesApplet.java:5: error: EmployeesApplet is not abstract and does not override  
> abstract method actionPerformed(ActionEvent) in ActionListener  
> public class EmployeesApplet extends JApplet implements ActionListener   
>    ^
> 1 error
> ```

I do not want to make `EmployeesApplet` `abstract` since it doesn't need to be.
My code is below, note I commented out the `implements ActionListener` and adding the `JButtons` as `ActionListener`

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class EmployeesApplet extends JApplet //implements ActionListener 
{
  public JButton              sd   = new JButton ("Salaried");
  public JButton              hr   = new JButton ("Hourly");
  public JButton              cm   = new JButton ("Commissioned");
  public JButton              cl   = new JButton ("Clear"); 

  private final int    FIELDS      =  8,   
                       FIELD_WIDTH = 20;   

  private String[]     strings     = new String[FIELDS];
  private TextFieldWithLabel[] tf  = new TextFieldWithLabel[FIELDS];
  private JTextArea    ta          = new JTextArea(5,25); 

     public void init()
     {
      String[]  s = {"First Name", "Last Name", "Employee ID", "(a) Salaried: Weekly Salary", "(b1) Hourly 1: Rate Per Hour", 
                   "(b2) Hourly 2: Hours Worked" , "(c1) Commissioned: Rate", "(c2) Commissioned: Gross Sales" };

       //----------------------
       //  Set up the Structure
       //----------------------

       Container c = getContentPane();
       JPanel f   = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
       JPanel b   = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(2,0));

       JPanel glb = new JPanel(new GridLayout(8,1,0,2));
       JPanel gtf = new JPanel(new GridLayout(8,1,0,2));
       JPanel flb = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());


       // Add FlowLayout to the container
       c.add(f);
       // Add BorderLayout to the FlowLayout
       f.add(b);

       //---------------------------------------
       //Add JPanels to the BorderLayout regions
       //---------------------------------------

       // Add JLables to GridLayout in West
       b.add(glb, BorderLayout.WEST);
       for (int i = 0; i < tf.length; i++)
       {
        tf[i] = new TextFieldWithLabel(s[i], FIELD_WIDTH);
        glb.add(tf[i].getLabel());
       }

       // Add JTextFeilds to GridLayout in East
       b.add(gtf, BorderLayout.EAST);
       for (int i = 0; i < tf.length; i++)
       {
        tf[i] = new TextFieldWithLabel(s[i], FIELD_WIDTH);
        tf[i].getTextField();
        gtf.add(tf[i].getTextField());
       }

       // Add JButtons to FlowLayout in South
       b.add(flb, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

       flb.add(sd);
       flb.add(hr);
       flb.add(cm);
       flb.add(cl);

       //sd.addActionListener(this);
       //hr.addActionListener(this);
       //cm.addActionListener(this);
       //cl.addActionListener(this);

       // Add JTextArea and make it not editable   
       f.add(ta);
       ta.setEditable(false);

     }

     public void readFields()
     {
     }

     public void fieldsExist()
     {
     }

     public void fieldsEmpty()
     {
     }

     public void actionPerformed()
     {
     }


}
```

Comment: So in order to implement ActionListener there as to be the actionPerformed method? Yes your suggestion to add that parameter fixed the problem, I'm just trying to understand it now

Comment: I have edited my answer to explain how to fix the problem, as well as why the parameter is required.

Answer (score 3):

Your `actionPerformed` method needs an `ActionEvent` as it's parameter:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

}
```

Otherwise you won't be overriding [the method defined in `ActionListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionListener.html#actionPerformed-java.awt.event.ActionEvent-) - you'll just be creating a new method. Since `ActionListener` is an interface, you are required to implement all the methods defined in the interface, hence the error.

---

The `actionPerformed` method is declared with the `ActionEvent` parameter to pass the method details about the event (which component triggered the event, the [action command](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/event/ActionEvent.html#getActionCommand--), etc..). Without the `ActionEvent` parameter, there is no *easy* way to gather such information. When an action is performed, an `ActionEvent` object is created, filled with the event information, then your `actionPerformed` method is invoked, which the `ActionEvent` object is passed in as an argument.

Comment: @Beeeee Without the `ActionEvent e`, how does the listener know what it is listening to?

Answer (score 0):

Your class is implementing the interface `ActionListener`

hence you have 2 options... make the class abstract or implement the method `actionPerformed`

the first one looks like what you need....

so try doing something like:

```
public class EmployeesApplet extends JApplet implements ActionListener {
     ....
     ....
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
```